# Inserting Image In With Form Page

Tags: css, image, forms, web

I am trying to insert an image into the large white space on the right hand side of this page. 
http://www.jobspark.ca/post-a-job/

I am trying to accomplish this using CSS. This is what I have so far.

```
#modulePage19099472 
{ background-image: url (http://www.jobspark.ca/storage/postjobimage.jpg);
background-position: right;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
padding: 0 0 0 0; 
margin: 0 0 0 0; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to apply your styles to the ".form-body" class, not "#modulePage19099472". Try the following CSS:

```
.form-body{
    background-image: url("http://www.jobspark.ca/storage/postjobimage.jpg");
    background-position: right top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 54% auto; 
 }
```

Make sure there's no space between "url" and the open parenthesis.

Comment: Thanks! that worked perfect. I am just looking to move the image over a bit to the left so that it flush with the form boxes. http://www.jobspark.ca/post-a-job/

Comment: Glad to hear it. To bump the image to the left you can substitute right with pixel values to position it exactly.

Comment: Darn I had one last little question for you. I am just trying to round the corners of that image and cant seem to get them to work. I used that same method that worked for all my other images

Comment: Hmm, I believe to round the corners of a background image you'll need to put the image in it's own div and round the corners of the div.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the selector is false. In your page's source, I can see `id="formOuterContainer19099472"`, not `id="modulePage19099472"`.